# Creating buttons programmatically inside a textview

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to replicate this feature inside iOS. I have the tableview working fine. But I cannot figure out the best approach to creating the buttons inside the textfield.

[image: Drop down]

[image]

I was thinking of changing to a textview or would I have to? I guess my main problem is writing logic to figure out the correct constraints for each button while maintaining the correct cursor position and wrapping to the next line. If anyone could give me an idea it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think maybe using collection view is an easier approach. So each tag is a collection view cell, and only the last cell has a textfield in it.

Comment: @EricQian thank you! I will try that.